# SAS 9.3 Giving Access to a particular table from one server to the user on the other user

Tags: sas

I have 2 SAS 9.3 servers Server-A and Server-B which have seperate libraries, datasets and users.

There are five tables in a library on SERVER A called LIB_A:
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5

I want to share only dataset A3 with another user from Server B.

A3 is a dynamic table so i decided to make a SAS view out of it called V_A3 and store it in a new library called LIB_B.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE VIEW LIB_B.V_A3 AS
SELECT * FROM LIB_A.A3;
QUIT;
RUN:
```

How can i share this V_A3 SAS view which is on Server A in library LIB_A with a user from Server B?

I have tried to create a new library on Server B and assign path as network share of the main folder of LIB_B (\SERVER B\LIB_B).

User sees the library and the view but view produces ERROR and data is not shown. Probably because the code which created the view references to the outher sources like

```
 SELECT * FROM LIB_A.A3
```

Without creating views, how can i keep the datasource dynamic?

On Server B, if i create a SAS BASE library which uses path of the original folder on Server A as;

\Server A\LIB_A

user sees all the five tables: A1,A2,A3,A4,A5.

But I want him to see only table A3. If i can manage this, there will be no need to create view.

How can i make it work? My servers are on Windows and SAS 9.3 T1M1.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to permission things at the table level, rather than at the folder level.  This is true whether you are using SAS Metadata Server to manage the permissions, or Windows.

In SAS Metadata Server, you could create an ACT `deny` (no read access) for `ServerBUsers`, and then you could separately create another ACT `permit` (read access) for `ServerBUsers`.  Then, apply the `deny` ACT to `\ServerA\LibA`, and apply the `permit` ACT to `\ServerA\LibA\TableA3`.

Windows permissions work roughly the same way, and your Windows permissions would have to be *at least as permissive* as your SAS permissions, or the user will get annoying messages.  If you are comfortable handling the permissions in SAS, then just give read access to the whole folder; but if not, you could create Windows AD groups akin to the ACTs above, and then have SAS use those Windows AD groups to define SAS user groups that then have permissions, or don't have permission, to the various files/folders.

Comment: And as a side note... 9.3 is REALLY old (9.4 was released [8 years ago next month](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/08/02/how-old-is-your-version-of-sas-release-dates-for-sas-software.html)!!)  Get on 9.4!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are planning to move to SAS VIYA but it will take some time. I have no experience on cretaing and working with ACLs on SAS. I will dig but can you recommend a video/source?

Comment: SAS has some training on their website, I think the initial part at least is free - I just took the administrator training a few years ago, and that covered this in detail.  They're not particularly different than any other ACT type thing - the ACT defines "permits" and "denies" and the user has the combination of any ACTs.